# Storage size of struct isn't known

Tags: c

I want to have my structure in the *main()* function scope.
When I do that and use **typedef** I get an error: `storage size of ... isn't known`

```c
typedef struct client client;

int main()
{


    struct client {
        int var;
        char c;
    };


    client person1;

    return 0;
}
```

I am doing this to get rid of the struct keyword.
Why do I get this error and how can I do it successfully with making the struct inside my *main()* function ?

Comment: so move the typedef into main()

Comment: The compiler first encounters `typedef struct client client;` which it doesn't know how to allocate global storage for, as `struct client` isn't defined in that scope.

Comment: By the way, unless you have good reason (namespace conflicts and etc), why not make the struct definition global? Defining the struct doesn't allocate memory. Declaring one does, within the scope it is defined.

Comment: @OldProgrammer why it works when i put it on jthe main function and not global

Comment: A typo in the name of a known struct (say `struct ustname` instead of `struct utsname` from  `sys/utsname.h` ) will also trigger this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting is because you actually have two types named `struct client` declared at different scopes.

The `typedef` declares a `struct client` at file scope and gives it the alias `client`.  When you then define `struct client` inside of the `main` function, it *masks* the one at file scope.  When you then attempt to declare a variable of type `client`, it refers to `struct client` at file scope which was never defined.

To fix this, the `typedef` and the struct definition need to be in the same scope.  So you can either put them both in `main`:

```
int main()
{
    typedef struct client client;
 
    struct client {
        int var;
        char c;
    };

    client person1;

    return 0;
}
```

Or both at file scope:

```
typedef struct client client;

struct client {
    int var;
    char c;
};

int main()
{
    client person1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and what if i want to put the type def in the first lines of the code ?

Comment: @random You mean specify the typdef at the same time as the struct definition?  You can do that too if you want, i.e. `typedef struct client { ... } client;`

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a `struct` right in `typedef`:

```
typedef struct client {
    int var;
    char c;
} client;


int main()
{
    client person1;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `typedef` should be used for the things that are already defined. In your case, the client is not defined in that scope. If you want a struct inside the main the try this

```
// in main
typedef struct client {
        int var;
        char c;
} client;

client person1;
```

or you can do this in the main

```
struct client {
        int var;
        char c;
    };

struct client person1;
```